# Convergence of $\int_0^1\int_0^1\vert u-v\vert^{\alpha-2}\frac{(uv)^\beta}{(u+v)^{\alpha+\beta}} dudv$

Tags: integration

I´m trying to determine if the following integral is finite or infinite

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\vert u-v\vert^{\alpha-2}\frac{(uv)^\beta}{(u+v)^{\alpha+\beta}} dudv$$
where $1<\alpha<2$, $1/2\leq \beta\leq 3/2$ and $0<\alpha-\beta\leq 1$.

Any suggestion will be very welcomed.

Comment: How is this related to fractoinal calculus?

Comment: Have you considered the transformation $s=\alpha-\beta$, $t=\alpha+\beta$?

Comment: As a starting point: When $\beta = 1$ you can do the double integral and get the answer $\frac{1}{2\alpha(\alpha-1)}$ which is obviously finite in the given range of $\alpha$.

Comment: @MarkFischler well, it is calculus... involving a fraction ;)

Comment: BTW: What do you need this for? Can you maybe add some background?

Comment: Yes for sure! It is the result of some technical computations! I´M analizing the holderianity of the increments of a SPDE (the heat equation driven by fractional white noise), For finishing them it was important to show that the integral is finite and I was very stucked, TVM for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is manifestly positive. Thus you can do a change of variables
$$
\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r \cos t \\ r \sin t \end{pmatrix}
$$
and estimate
$$
\left| \int_0^1\int_0^1\vert u-v\vert^{\alpha-2}\,\frac{(uv)^\beta}{(u+v)^{\alpha+\beta}} {\rm d}u \, {\rm d}v \right| \leq \left|\int_0^\sqrt{2} r^{\beta -1} \, {\rm d}r \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \vert \cos t- \sin t\vert^{\alpha-2}\,\frac{(\cos t \sin t)^\beta}{(\cos t+\sin t)^{\alpha+\beta}} \, {\rm d}t\right| \, .
$$
The $r$ integral is easy and shows that the issue point $0$ doesn't make any problems for $\beta>0$. The fraction in the $t$ integral is finite everywhere and can be estimated by a constant $c$ and you only have to show the finiteness of
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \vert \cos t- \sin t\vert^{\alpha-2}\,{\rm d}t \, .
$$
Due to symmetry I guess here it is enough to show that
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left( \cos t- \sin t\right)^{\alpha-2}\,{\rm d}t
$$
is finite. But $\cos t -\sin t \geq \frac{\pi}{4}-t$ and for $\alpha < 2$
$$
\left|\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left( \cos t- \sin t\right)^{\alpha-2}\,{\rm d}t \right| \leq \left| \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left( \frac{\pi}{4} - t\right)^{\alpha-2}\,{\rm d}t \right| = {\frac {\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{\alpha-1}}{\alpha-1}} \, .
$$
Thus $\alpha > 1$ is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the integral converges for $\alpha > 1, \beta >0.$

In the inside integral, let $u=vx.$ The expression becomes

$$\int_0^1v^{\beta -1}\int_0^{1/v} \frac{|x-1|^{\alpha-2} x^\beta}{(x+1)^{\alpha + \beta}}dx\,dv.$$

(Thanks to @Diger for correcting my error here.) Claim: For any $\alpha > 1,\beta > 0,$

$$\tag 1\int_0^{\infty} \frac{|x-1|^{\alpha-2} x^\beta}{(x+1)^{\alpha + \beta}}dx < \infty.$$

Proof of the claim: The only trouble spots are at $1$ and $\infty.$ But at $1$ we have an integrable singularity due to $\alpha >1,$ and at $\infty$ the integrand is on the order of $1/x^2.$ This implies the claim.

Let $C$ be the value of the integral in $(1).$ The integral of interest is no more than $C\int_0^1v^{\beta -1}\,dv.$ Because $\beta >0,$ we have the claimed convergence for the original integral.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, but for completeness I guess you missed a factor $v^{\beta-1}$.

Comment: @Diger You're quite right. Thanks for the correction.